# Use of Possessive or objective case of pronoun

Tags: pronouns, possessive-pronouns

> The car of (them/their) is just amazing!

What should I use, possessive pronoun or objective case 
I like a thing of them/someone is sounding good to me.yet I'm perplexed!

Answer (score 1):

"[Theirs](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/theirs)" is to be used here.
But you can use both of the following:

> The car of theirs is just amazing!
>   Their car is just amazing!

Comment: Just to note: the latter is way more natural to say.

Comment: What about ***That** car of theirs is just amazing*? Wouldn't that sound better in the first example?

Comment: @Smock Not necessarily. Only if you're pointing out to a car.

Comment: @BellaSwan or just referencing someone's car in conversation (at least in BrE). [talking about the Robertsons] *That car of theirs is just amazing* sounds much more natural to me (lacking any context in the OP to the contrary)

Comment: I believe we use "that" when the thing(here car)  has previously been talked about!

Answer (score 0):

Their is subject, them is object. You would mostly use 'them' at the end of a sentence i.e. something is done to them, or I took the car belonging to them. The word 'Their' always precedes something which belongs to 'them'. i.e. Their Car their holiday etc. I hope this makes it a little clearer.